# How to properly escape shell commands in ExecStart?

Tags: shell, systemd

Running this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Save a screenshot
Wants=screenshot.timer

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'DISPLAY=:0 scrot /home/myuser/Pictures/Journal/$(date +"%s").png'

[Install]
```

Results in:

```
scrot: Saving to file /home/myuser/Pictures/Journal//usr/bin/zsh.png failed: No such file or directory
```

Why? The same command, run in a shell, works:

```
% /bin/sh -c 'DISPLAY=:0 scrot /home/myuser/Pictures/Journal/$(date +"%s").png'
% echo $?
0
%
```

The command I use is:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload && systemctl --user start screenshot.service; systemctl --user status screenshot.service
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A systemd unit can make use of [various "specifiers"](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) in a number of fields, one of which is `%s`:

> | Specifier | Meaning | Detail |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `%s` | User shell | This is the shell of the user running the service manager instance. |
> | `%%` | Single percent sign | Use `%%` in place of `%` to specify a single percent sign. |

When you need to use `%` in a systemd unit in a field subject to specifier interpretation, use `%%` instead.

Comment: This answer makes me glad to actually have asked the question instead of working around the issue by calling an external script which in turn calls scrot. Thanks!